# Immutables Library Does Not Require Collection Attributes To Be Set

Tags: java, immutability, immutables-library

I recently started using the [Immutables](https://immutables.github.io/) library, and I'm puzzled by the following behavior:

Given the following abstract value type

```
@Value.Immutable
public abstract class Foo {
    public abstract String bar();

    public abstract List<String> baz();
}
```

attempting to build an object like so

```
ImmutableFoo.builder()
    .baz(List.of("1", "2", "3"))
    .build()
```

fails because

> some of required attributes are not set [bar]

yet

```
ImmutableFoo.builder()
    .bar("1, 2, 3")
    .build()
```

is fine, and there is no objection that `baz` has not been set.

Why do collection attributes receive different treatment?

Comment: They explicitly stated in their own documentation that "When building using builders, the contents of collection attributes can be left unspecified". You need to ask _them_ why, not _us_.

Comment: done: https://github.com/immutables/immutables/issues/1429